# How to Prevent Pandas converting dtype String to float

Tags: python, pandas

I have some columns that contains many digits(from 10 to 20 in length) and some of which contains some characters in them, some of them are blank or NaN. When opening the file, read_csv,

```
dfMain = pd.read_csv('main.csv', 
                 dtype={'Doc Num': np.object_},
                 converters={'Product Number': lambda x: str(x)})

dfMain.dtype
Doc Num           int64
Product Number    object
dtype: object
```

But when i try to merge it with another Dataframe, or even filter it will show:

```
dfMain[dfMain['Doc Num']=='ABC123456']]
ABC123456     1.53E+11
```

It's fine even if it does this, but the problem is that when it saves as csv, the column values are saved as:

```
153000000000
```

Ive tried adding a prefix to the column:

```
dfMain['Product number'] = 'x' + dfMain['Product number']
```

but will still give

```
dfMain[dfMain['Doc Num']=='ABC123456']]
ABC123456     x1.53E+11
```

Comment: Does `dtype={'Doc Num': str}` work?

Comment: nope, tried many combinations of it.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Never mind, my csv files are the problem.